# Opencv with blender or opengl?

Tags: opencv, opengl, blender, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

I am new to opencv,I did a project with opencv,

My project is tracking object with stereo camera,so I find where is the object and I want to represent it in (blender or with opengl or another one),so my situation is that I have point 3d in YML file and I want to represent them . I dont know what I will use ,can any one help me ??

Comment: my project is similar to this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M91PY2lsqIU ,so I have 3d coordinate for each color and I want to represent them in 3D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to do in Blender, but for your simple purpose Opengl should be enough. To get started with Modern Opengl check this list of contents: [link](https://github.com/eug/awesome-opengl)

In opengl, before drawing anything you must "send" data (vertices) to your GPU. One part of this process is called Vertex Buffer Object. (its very simple after your program by yourself). When you use VBO, you can specify what type of data you have: **STATIC** or **DYNAMIC**.  Dynamic means that you (the artist) will change the data over time, the position of each vertex might change. And that is what you want.